# \hyperref does not lead to defined label

Tags: beamer, hyperref, labels

I have a beamer-class document and I defined a label directly after a \phantomsection.

```
\begin{frame}
\phantomsection
\label{sec:rotation}
<TEXT>
\end{frame}
```

However, referencing to the label with \hyperref[sec:rotation]{rotation} in another place creates a link that does NOT lead to the section where it is defined, but to the beginning of the document. How to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

`beamer` loads `hyperref` with option `implicit=false`. This influences behaviors of many user commands from `hyperref`. In your case, `\phantomsection` is now an empty macro (defined by `\let\phantomsection\@empty`).

To add a label to frame, you can use option `label={<label name>}` of `frame` environment.

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[label={sec:rotation}]
  content
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  % print "macro:->"
  \meaning\phantomsection 
  
  % clicking "rotation" jumps to first frame
  \hyperref[sec:rotation]{rotation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```